# How to set values in  Backing Bean in JSF  from Session listener or Servlet?

Tags: session, jsf, servlets, listener, managed-bean

In `SessionListener` I want to set some values of `@ManagedBean` with `Session scope` that I want to show in JSF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to create the managed bean instance yourself.

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
bean.setSomething(something);
event.getSession().setAttribute("bean", bean); // "bean" is managed bean name.
```

JSF will just reuse it if it already exist in the session scope (you see, the JSF "session scope" is under the covers represented by attributes of `HttpSession`). Note that this way any `@PostConstruct` won't be invoked and any dependencies which needs to be injected by `@ManagedProperty`, `@EJB`, etc, won't be injected at all. You'd need to do it yourself as well.

Designtechnically, much better is to perform the job just in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` method of the backing bean class itself.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Here.
    }

}
```